# Locbaml /generate gives error "Type reference cannot find public type named '...'"

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, localization, locbaml

I'm using Locbaml to generate localization files in my WPF application.

Yesterday, I've upgraded my solutions from VS2008 to VS2010, and since then Locbaml throws an error in two of my assemblies saying

"Type reference cannot find public type named 'String'." in one assembly and

"Type reference cannot find public type named 'Int32'." in the second assembly.

I indeed use those types in my xaml and they all look the same:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
DataType="{x:Type sys:Int32}"
DataType="{x:Type sys:String}"
```

That's even not some custom type I could've make something wrong with.

Any ideas of how this can be fixed, or what is causing this?

Many thanks,

**EDIT:**
I've tried to google this and all I could find is a possible problem with assembly names that have whitespaces in it
([https://siderite.dev/blog/vs2008-wpf-designer-throws-error-type.html](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2009/06/vs2008-wpf-designer-throws-error-type.html))
- this is not my case.

Also, I should specify that the solution compiles.

Comment: I'm sure by now you have cleaned/rebuiled your project again but that didn't cure it right? I have had these sort of issues (not only from  migrating but also from renaming projects) the fastest way is I guess recreating the project again in VS2010. This way which version of the assembly you are referencing to easily gets solved. good luck

Comment: It's a old question, but I think the problem is explained in this [post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443138/type-reference-cannot-find-public-type-named

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still haven't figured out what is causing this, but fortunately I could spare the "DataType=..", and removing them solved the problem.